# Slowness in react redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am facing issues with performance of my application. I have some component like below. I added some console times to dig deep into the possible issue and these are the findings.

GridRenderTime ~ 2-5 ms

GridRenderOverallTime ~ 5 seconds

Huge difference. I am not sure what else processing is happening between componentWillUpdate and componentDidUpdate that is not getting captured by metric "GridRenderTime".

```
export default class Grid extends Component {

     componentWillUpdate() {
        console.time('GridRenderOverallTime');
     }

     componentDidUpdate() {
        console.timeEnd('GridRenderOverallTime');
     }

     render() {
         return (
           <div>
              {console.time('GridRenderTime')}
              <BulkActionPanel
                  actions={this.bulkActions}
                  selectedJobIds={this.getFromConfig(this.props.config, [SELECTED_ROWS_PATH_IN_GRID_CONFIG])}
             />
              <SlickGrid
                  data={this.props.jobGridData}
              />
              <UserInputModal />
              <ActionConfirmationModal />
              <ConfigModal />
              <ChangeChkptStatusModal />
              <ResponseModal />
              <CommandModalBox />
              {console.timeEnd('GridRenderTime')}
          </div>
     } }
```

As the number of rows passed to SlickGrid increases,  GridRenderOverallTime increases proportionally.

Leads here are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a shot at [why-did-you-update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update), it may help understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open the developer tools window. Then select the Network tab to view network activity. Next select the Performance tab. Follow the instructions there to get a detailed view of the performance bottlenecks in your page.